# Erro lógico ao ordenar vetor em par e impar

Tags: c, algoritmo

Bom, eu estava tentando ordenar um vetor em par e ímpar, ou seja, metade do vetor é par e a outra ímpar. Funcionou "quase" perfeitamente.

O problema é que a ultima posição sempre acabava sendo par. E eu não consegui achar o erro.

Desde já, gratidão.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int vector[10];
    int aux = 0;

    printf("Digite 10 numeros a serem ordenados em par e impar:\n");

    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        scanf("%d", &vector[x]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 10; j > 0; j--) {

            if (vector[i] % 2 == 1) {
                aux = vector[i];
                vector[i] = vector[j];
                vector[j] = aux;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int t = 0; t < 10; t++) {
        printf("%d", vector[t]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu código estava correto, a não ser por um detalhe nos `for` encadeado.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int vector[10];
    int aux = 0;

    printf("Digite 10 numeros a serem ordenados em par e impar:\n");

    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        scanf("%d", &vector[x]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

            if (vector[i] % 2 == 0) {
                aux = vector[i];
                vector[i] = vector[j];
                vector[j] = aux;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int t = 0; t < 10; t++) {
        printf("\n%d", vector[t]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Um deles ia de 0 até 9 e o de dentro ia de 10 até 1, também alterei o valor de comparação de 1 pra 0, o que não afeta muito.

Comment: Perdão, mas qual era o erro no loop? Não identifiquei ainda kk

Comment: Era o range deles, não cobria o vetor inteiro, a última posição ficava de fora da comparação.

Answer (score -2):

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
int vector[10];
int aux = 0;

```
//Receber e armazenar os valores do vetor.
for (int x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
    printf("Digite valor do %dº vetor: ", x);
    scanf("%d", &vector[x]);
}
//Ordenar números pares
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {

        if (vector[i] % 2 == 0) {
            aux = vector[i];
            vector[i] = vector[j];
            vector[j] = aux;
        }
    }
}

printf("\n");
for (int t = 1; t <= 10; t++) {
    if (vector[t] % 2 == 0) {
    printf("Vetor Par: %d\n", vector[t]); //imprimir valores pares.
    }
}

printf("\n");

for (int t = 1; t <= 10; t++) {
    if (vector[t] % 2 != 0) {
    printf("Vetor Ímpar: %d\n", vector[t]); //imprimir valores ímpares
    }
}

return 0;
```

}